# Can I check noatime with touching a file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, date

As far as I know when `atime` is set (which is the default) if I touch a file its datetime will be updated:

`0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  5 11:57 my_file`

When I touch the file the date will be updated. I have set `noatime` and rebooted the server and now when I touch the file date will be updated again. Shouldn't it be the same as before? I supposed that touching a file will not change the access time of the file.

Is this true?

I have checked the partition with `mount -l` and noatime is present:

```
/dev/mapper/database-var on /var type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=1024,noquota)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`noatime` disables the implicit access time updates (those that occur as a side-effect of an operation on a file); it doesn’t affect explicit access time updates (where a program explicitly asks the operating system to update a file’s access time). When you `touch` a file, you’re explicitly asking to update the access and modification times, and that’s what happens.

You can `touch` a file without changing the access time, by using the `-m` option; only the modification time will be updated.

Comment: I used `touch -m my_file` and again time is updated. I checked with `ls -l my_file`

Comment: Well yes, because `ls -l` shows the modification time; use `ls -l --time=access` to see the access time.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the time +1. I actually didn't know about explicit and implicit access time.

Comment: @ALH It's not the access time that is implicit or explicit, it's the updating of the access time. When using `touch`, you explicitly update the timestamp. When accessing a file with e.g. an editor, you implicitly update the timestamp (if `atime` is the active mount option).

Comment: Good to know. Now I can force Android to update last played time on my songs.